# "Data is not compatible with column definition or is not available for a not nullable column" problem Oracle SQL developer 18c

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to import data from a txt file that contains roughly 1M rows into 50 attributes table

the problem is, SQL developer doesn't seem to recognize the appropriate date format for one of my columns (which is a DATE column)

(this is the first time I use oracle developer)

here is the problem:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If month's mask is `mm`, it can't be valid for minutes - use `mi` instead. So:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss
```

Comment: Should point out the other mistake too: The OP used `hh` instead of `hh24`, and an input like '17' would be rejected also.